# Access list of cipher suites from TLS client_hello in JSSE

Tags: java, jsse

I'd like my TLS server app to keep stats on which cipher suites its clients have requested -- so that in future I can make informed decisions about the user impact of disabling a given cipher suite.

Using JSSE I can easily get at the cipher suite agreed upon by the handshake, using `HandshakeCompletedEvent.getCipherSuite()`.

But browsing through the Javadocs, I can't see anything that lets me see details of the client_hello, and thus the other cipher suites listed as acceptable to the client. Is there an API into that, that I've failed to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But browsing through the Javadocs, I can't see anything that lets me see details of the client_hello, and thus the other cipher suites listed as acceptable to the client.

There isn't one.

> Is there an API into that, that I've failed to find?

No.

You shouldn't disable any cipher suite unless there is a security problem with it, and in that case it is just bad luck if any client relied on it. This is really very unlikely.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to be the case. Unfortunately in some commercial situations like mine, "just bad luck if any client relied on it" doesn't cut it. Customers order of preference is "working with secure cipher" > "working with weak cipher" > "not working at all" -- and their contracts reflect that.

And "availability" is part of "security".

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If a specific customer wants to use a  particular cipher suite ***let him configure it at his end.*** If you configure it at your end all you will accomplish is ruling out some other other specific customer.